# How can scalac be used on a source with spaces in it?

Tags: scalac

The man page for the command (http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/tools/scalac.html) does not explain how to do this.

The obvious workaround it to simply change the file name to avoid spaces, but this is not a solution.

I am using windows and running scalac from command prompt.

I have tried:

- scalac the source file name.scala => error: source file 'the' could not be found
- scalac "the source file name.scala" => source was unexpected at this time.
- scalac 'the source filename.scala' => error: source file ''the' could not be found
- scalac `the source file name.scala` => error: source file '`the' could not be found
- scalac -sourcepath the source filename.scala => error: source file 'source' could not be found
- scalac -sourcepath "the source filename.scala" => Usage: scalac
- scalac -sourcepath 'the source filename.scala' => error: source file 'source' could not be found.
- scalac -sourcepath the\ source\ filename.scala => error: source file 'source\' could not be found.
- scalac -sourcepath the^ source^ filename.scala => error: source file 'source' could not be found
- scalac the^ source^ filename.scala => error: source file 'the' could not be found

I imagine I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: As stated in the third paragraph, Windows.

Comment: Most likely a bug in our runner script. Could you please report it to https://issues.scala-lang.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa?

Comment: As requested, I have now reported it as a bug.